# Regex check the first character before and after given character

Tags: php, regex

How do i check if the first character before `or` after a `/` is a `?`?

```
$str = 'some/text/?goes/here?/andhere?/?'
```

So far i managed to check after `/`:

```
preg_match_all('/\/(?=\?)/', $str, $matches)
```

This matches the `/?` patter. Now how do i make it to also match the `?/`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you version of PHP supports it, there are "lookbehinds" as well as lookaheads, like this:

`preg_match_all('/(?<=\?)\/|\/(?=\?)/', $str, $matches)`

(Lookbehind might have been in PHP for a long time, maybe even from the start. The only reason I feel a bit uncertain is that I do most of my work in JavaScript these days, and lookbehind still isn't supported by the JavaScript in many web browsers.)

Comment: I tried something like this but it will match only `?/?` instead of `?/` or `/?`

Comment: I could add an or but i'm sure there's a better version of what i'm trying to get out of it

Comment: Yep, I definitely missed that my pattern would only match `?\?`. Oops! I can't think of anything better than your previous version of this, however, even if it does seem repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

The *quickest* way to do this is using a conditional (which is inherently faster
than an alternation ).

`/(?(?<!\?.)(?=\?))`

https://regex101.com/r/H9HxHN/1

Explained

```
 /                     # Forward slash
 (?(?<! \? . )         # Conditional: Not a ?/ behind ?
      (?= \? )              # True, then must be a ? ahead
 )                          # No match is implicit failure
```

Benchmark
(this regex is twice as fast as the other one)

```
Regex1:   /(?(?<!\?.)(?=\?))
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.26 s,   264.13 ms,   264125 µs
Matches per sec:   567,912


Regex2:   (?<=\?)\/|\/(?=\?)
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.49 s,   489.92 ms,   489919 µs
Matches per sec:   306,173
```

Comment: That is a very nice solution +1 Out of curiosity, what makes the alternation that much slower than the conditional? Great benchmark tool btw.

Comment: @Thefourthbird - I believe that alternations have open ended multiple pathways to manage within the backtrack mechanism. Where as a conditional are immune to backtracking and has 2 basic paths without the overhead of alternations.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a cleaner solution:

```
(\W)(?=\W)
```

Basically this means: true if there is any special character after a special character.

So all this would be true: `?/` `/?` `?/?`

**Warning:** do not use this if you're searching just for a specific special character because this regex checks for ANY special character that has ANY special character right after it!

In my case however i don't mind, i don't want ANY special character coming right after `/` so it's even better than what i was looking for.